# IntelliJ's show diff always compare with a same old git commit

Tags: git, intellij-idea

This is a strange problem I'm observing in my IntelliJ. The show-diff always compare the current local version with same old commit of git which is NOT the latest commit. Ideally it should  compare it with latest commit.
If the file was created after that commit then the error is "Not a valid object name ".
To bypass this problem I have to RightClick->Git->Compare with and then select latest version.
Any clue what could be the issue?
I have tried to search this commit id in the IntelliJ project folder but I could'nt find any. Also updated the Git CMD to latest version but no relief.

Comment: Have you fetched all the commits from your remote branch?

Comment: Yes, I‘m facing this problem for more than a week and I keep local branch updated

Comment: Diff could be called in multiple places in the IDE, also the actions showing it can be different. So what exact action do you use? Is it Show Diff in the Local Changes?

Comment: Yes, Show diff in the local changes.

Answer (score 3):

To show diff for a file from Local changes IntelliJ calls `git log -n1 HEAD -- path/to/file` to get hash of the latest revision, and then gets file content with `git cat-file -p hash:path/to/file`. The latter is the result for Not a valid object name error.

Seems either HEAD is incorrectly resolved by git, which I really doubt, or there is something (e.g. a third-party plugin like Git Scope) that alters the logic.

One more possible reason - a tricky nested Git repo that includes the history up to the problematic commit. In this case, the Diff might be requested from that repo.

You could check the error and all the commands IDE executes enabling debug logging (use **Help - Debug Log Settings...**) for `#git4idea.commands.GitHandler`.

Comment: I added the debug log settings -> git4idea.commands.GitHandler:trace   but I don't see any trace when show-diff is executed. Though, I see other logs tarces when I fetch the or switch branches or any other commands

Comment: show diff is not executed. it is `git log -n1 HEAD -- <path/to/file>` to find the latest revision of the file, and then `git cat-file -p <hash>:<path/to/file>` to get the content to diff current state with. check in which roots they are executed, and also double check the commands in the command line to make sure they return correct content.

Comment: This is pointing to the latest commit which is correct, I found the problem with another clone of the same repo that has unstaged commit and when I executed this command there then I found that problematic commit. Fixing that repo solved the problem.

Comment: The problem reoccurred again even I cleaned all the other git clones point to that repo and restarted InetlliJ with cache invalidation. Something wrong with IntelliJ only, I have eclipse also configured to same repo but that works well.

Comment: It is impossible to tell something without getting full details on the issue - what is shown, what should be shown, how is your IDE configured in regards to VCs roots, etc. If it is not clear from the logs what happens, consider submitting a ticket to Jetbrains support

Comment: “One more possible reason - a tricky nested Git repo that includes the history up to the problematic commit. In this case, the Diff might be requested from that repo.” This was the reason on my machine. *Solution:* 1) Find `.git` subdirectories: `find ./ -type d -name ".git"` or open PHPStorm → Git → Manage Remotes . 2) Remove all unwanted Git subdirectories.